# MySQL: Within a transaction, can I use the result of a SELECT in an IF statement?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, transactions

I want to check whether a Location entry already exists in the database so within a transaction I use a select.

`select @location_id := location_id from location where city = "London" and country_code = "GB";`

But after this I want the location to be made if @location_id returns nothing, otherwise I will use the existing @location_id. I am thinking something like this may work.

```
delimiter $$
if @location_id is null then
    select @location_id := max(location_id) from location;
    set @location_id = @location_id + 1;
    insert into location (location_id, city, country_code)
    values(@location_id, "London", "GB");
end if; $$
delimiter ;
```

(To clarify: location_id is an auto_incremented integer value in the location table)

Can this usage of an "if statement" work within a transaction or perhaps within a function taking the @location_id or a procedure?

Answer (score 0):

With further investigation I realised I had to use a procedure as you cannot do a select within a function. In the end my solution was:

```
    delimiter $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE location_processor(in _city varchar(20),
    in _country_code varchar(2), out id int)
    begin
    select location_id into id from calendar.location
    where city = _city and country_code = _country_code limit 0,1;
    if id is null then
       select @id := max(location_id) from calendar.location;
       if @id is null then
          set @id = 0;
       end if;
       set @id = @id + 1;
       insert into calendar.location (location_id, city, country_code)
       values(@id, _city, _country_code);
       set id = @id;
    end if;
    end; $$
    delimiter ;
```

And I called this using:

```
call calendar.location_processor("London", "GB", @id);
select @id;
```